# Automated cross-platform testing of mobile applications

Tags: testing, mobile, automated-tests

I have a cross-platform mobile application (WindowsMobile, Android, Symbian), written in C++ for performance reasons. This application has quite an extensive GUI.

What would be the best way to automate its testing? My first ideas was to use emulators but I hear that it is not very reliable to test this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the Amazon device farm. It's a paid service of  but it was a great experience to work with this tool. Happy testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [appium](http://appium.io) for this.

Real iOS device: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/mobile-web.md#mobile-safari-on-a-real-ios-device

Real Android device: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/mobile-web.md#mobile-chrome-on-emulator-or-real-device